# How Can I Communicate with another application?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, sdk

I'd like ask you if there's a way to send information or commands to other applications.
For example: a person is typing a message to one, and after ten seconds my program adds (by using the command append("text").to(EditText); ) a string like "hello" in the EditText  of the message.

I discovered that information can be shared between different apps through ContentProviders

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible when the developer of this particular app predicted such behavior. It could be done simply by broadcasting intents between apps, but this "another" app must have a suitable Broadcast Receiver to make a use of this intents. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can fire up an intent on another app and bundle your Data into it and pass it through `Intent` object. Check out [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) link. I purposely haven't written a code. I think everyone should learn on their own. Remember,The developer site is the Bible for Android.

Comment: Could I use that process , to copy and past ???:
 final ClipboardManager clipBoard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
  
     copynPaste.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    clipBoard.setText(src.getText());
    dest.setText(clipBoard.getText());
    
   }});

Comment: Your data is in only text format right? Then you can use a `Bundle`(link-http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) and then initialize your `Intent` and use [Your Intent].addData([Your Bundle Name])